# How to map two lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a optimal solution where i can map elements of multiple lists and display output in following format given below.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['d','e','f']
list3 = [1,2,3]
```

output expected

```
ad1
be2
cf3
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: use `zip`, `+`  and `str`.

Comment: I tried mapping using simple nested loops, but output is not as i expect it either maps everything or skips index.

Comment: `list(map(''.join,zip(list1,list2,map(str,list3))))` -> `['ad1', 'be2', 'cf3']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with map function as well, but if with loop, here's your answer. We have to concatenate the first elements of all three list, second with second and third with third. So make a loop going from zero to len(<any_list>) [because all three list have same len] and concatenate all three. Your code:

```
list1=["a","b","c"]
list2=["d","e","f"]
list3=[1,2,3]
list4=[]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    list4. append (list1[i]+list2[i]+str(list3[i]))

print(*list4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops do **not** achieve **parallel** iteration of multiple iterables. They are suited when you want to pair every element from one iterable with ervery element from another ("Cartesian product"). For parallel (pair/tuple-wise) iteration, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x in zip(list1, list2, list3):   
    print("".join(map(str, x)))
# ad1
# be2
# cf3
```

Some documentation:

- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Comment: Or `print(*x, sep='')`

Comment: Yeah, I don't generally like the extra gimmicks of `print` as `print` should never be used to achieve coding logic. It rarely serves more than a debugging purpose in the real world. Here, the single argument to `print` is ready for any usage, e.g. adding it to a collection or further manipulation.